# Karma won't run (socket.io throwing error)

Tags: node.js, angular, karma-runner, travis-ci

I have an Angular 2 project, written in Typescript. I am trying to get Travis CI set up. Unfortunately, I am getting an error thrown from Karma:

> Missing error handler on `socket`.
>
> TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function

#### Expected behavior

My Travis CI build to complete the Jasmine Unit tests defined, reporting the number run and success vs. failure.

#### Actual behavior

This is the output from my build log. [Here](https://travis-ci.org/georgeedwards/Gen-App/builds/120847556) is the full build log. Also, [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Gen-App/commit/fba70d6960b88ea01858ef8b1fc26eece1e49e34) is the full github repository that was being built.

```
[09:39:04] Starting 'client.unit_test'...
05 04 2016 09:39:04.281:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
05 04 2016 09:39:04.287:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
05 04 2016 09:39:05.519:INFO [Chrome 49.0.2623 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#7wcOJ3uFvZX-HgZeAAAA with id 49035067
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function
  at /home/travis/build/georgeedwards/Gen-App/node_modules/karma/lib/reporter.js:45:23
  at [object Object].onBrowserError (/home/travis/build/georgeedwards/Gen-App/node_modules/karma/lib/reporters/base.js:58:60)
```

#### Enviroment Details

Node v5.10.0

Angular 2.0.0-beta.12

```
├── karma@0.13.22 
├── karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.12 
├── karma-coverage@0.2.7 
├── karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.7 
├── karma-ie-launcher@0.1.5 
├── karma-jasmine@0.3.8 
├── karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.2 
├── karma-opera-launcher@0.1.0 
├── karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4
```

Any ideas what may be causing this, or what info you might need to debug this?

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1969 ?

Comment: @MarcoL yes, there seem to be quite a few similar issues, but none of the resolution steps have helped me solve this issue...

Comment: I got the same error when upgrade to Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2, according to angular-cli docs, angular-cli-build.json is not required, and karma-test-shim.js should be removed. The sources can be compiled and test railed.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen issues similar to this in the past. 99% of the time this is related to not including a file in the `karma.conf.js` files array that is reference by the app.

Another likely issue is that module names are not correctly being translated from their respective file ref names.

Here is a snippet from my `karma-test-shim.js` where I translate my file names to module names:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        'base/wwwroot/app': {
            defaultExtension: false,
            format: 'register',
            map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).
                  filter(function onlyAppFiles(filePath) {
                      return /^\/base\/wwwroot\/app\/.*\.js$/.test(filePath)
                  }).
                  reduce(function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
                      // creates local module name mapping to global path with karma's fingerprint in path, e.g.:
                      var moduleName = appPath.replace(/^\/base\/wwwroot\/app\//, './').replace(/\.js$/, '');
                      pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath];
                      return pathsMapping;
                  }, {})
        }
    }
});
```

The structure of my project is:

```
/
 karma.conf.js
 karma-test-shim.js
 wwwroot/
         app/
             //Angular 2 project and spec files
```

Julie Ralph, a dev on the Angular 2 team, has a [seed project](https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed) for setting up karma tests for an Angular 2 project which I found to be very helpful when creating the karma shim.